# Модификаторы доступа программы расчета по формуле

Tags: python, python-3.x

вводит в ступор это задание
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сказали реализовать его через классы с модификаторами доступа, а я не работал с модификаторами доступа в python и еще плохо понимаю как реализовать все это через методы. Надеюсь, что поможете

```
class qqq:
    def w(self):
        self.f = 1.03 * self.v + math.pow(self.e, 2) + 
        math.fabs(math.tag(self.x))
        return f
```

немного бред но я пытался:(
без модификаторов пытался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math

class Calc:
    def __init__(self, v, y, x):
        self.__v = v # поле "private"
        self.__y = y # поле "private"
        self.__x = x # поле "private"

    def W(self):
        return 1.03 * self.__v + math.exp(2 * self.__y) + math.tan(abs(self.__x))

calc = Calc(1.1, 0.004, 0.2)
#print(calc.__v) При раскомментировании вызовет ошибку, так как поле "private"
print(calc.W())
```

Comment: Можно добавить что private как такового нет, просто из вне методы/поля, начинающиеся на `__` стали доступны с именем класса, пример как получить доступ к `__v`: `print(calc._Calc__v)`